# How post more than one variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

There is 2 input type="text". First, user input 1st input text area with id="ncr_no". Then, cursor is  in 2nd input type "text" with id="itm_cd". Now, I want to make, how the two input by user, when cursor is in 2nd input type, posted to other php (get_ncrnoitmcd.php) by javascript? That's the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#itm_cd").keyup(function (e) {
            $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, ''));

            var itm_cd = $(this).val();

            if(itm_cd.length < 1){$("#user-result3").html('');return;}

            if(itm_cd.length >= 1 ){
                $("#user-result3").html('<img src="image/ajax-loader.gif" />');
                $.post('get_ncrnoitmcd.php', {'itm_cd':itm_cd},  function(data) {
                  $("#user-result3").html(data);
                });
            }
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Thank a lot.

Comment: Try `$.post('get_ncrnoitmcd.php', {'itm_cd':itm_cd, key2: value2, key3:value3 ... },`

Comment: can't works...@joyBlanks :(

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you can send the 2 values to server on 2nd element keyup after validation. Whats the problem that you are facing? I also added ncr_no in the post request.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#itm_cd").keyup(function (e) {
                $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, ''));
                var itm_cd = $(this).val();
                if(itm_cd.length < 1){
                    $("#user-result3").html('');
                    return;
                }else if(itm_cd.length >= 1 ){
                    $("#user-result3").html('<img src="image/ajax-loader.gif" />');
                    $.post(
                        'get_ncrnoitmcd.php'
                       ,{'itm_cd':itm_cd,'ncr_no':$('#ncr_no').val()}
                       ,function(data) {
                           $("#user-result3").html(data);
                       }
                    );
                }
            }); 
        });
</script>
```

Comment: still can't work @joyBlanks. I answer my problem above. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I want to get available or not available, Mr. @joyBlanks

```
<?php
//connection.php

if(isset($_POST["itm_cd"],$_POST["ncr_no"]))
{
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
        die();
    }

    $connecDB = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password,$db_name)or die('could not connect to database');
    $itm_cd =  strtolower(trim($_POST["itm_cd"])); 
    $itm_cd = filter_var($itm_cd, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW|FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
    $results = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT itm_cd,ncr_no FROM sqc_ncr WHERE itm_cd ='$itm_cd' AND ncr_no ='$ncr_no'");
    $itm_cd_exist = mysqli_num_rows($results); 
    if($itm_cd_exist) {
        die('<!--img src="image/available.png" /--> <i>Available in database</i>');
    }else{
        die('<!--img src="image/not-available.png" /--> <i>Not Available in database</i>');
    }
    mysqli_close($connecDB);
}
?>
```

Comment: You have lot of problems in this php. you need to check 2 conditions separated by `&&` not `,` in first line you are not getting the ncr_no in a variable but you are using that variable. do check if the http_x_requsted_with is returning true or false, I dont think you even need that until and unless you specifically want it to be w/o ajax

Comment: Mr. joyBlanks. I've not used , and used && and not used http_x_requested, but available or not available in html not shown. <td><input type="text" class="input" name="itm_cd" id="itm_cd"  onBlur="updateItemName()" required /> <span id="user-result3"></span></td>

Answer (score 0):

I've not used , and used && and not used http_x_requested, but available or not available in html not shown.

```
<td><input type="text" class="input" name="itm_cd" id="itm_cd"  onBlur="updateItemName()" required /> <span id="user-result3"></span></td>
```